# Inject key into MapBinder

Tags: java, guice

I am trying to inject a Map into a class using Guice where the map has the form `Map<MyInterface, Integer>`.

I want to use the `MapBinder` extention to accomplish this, but it seems that MapBinder requires an instantiated object for the key.  I would like to have Guice inject instantiations of the key, since they are complex objects that require injections of their own.  I.e, something like:

```
MapBinder<MyInterface, Integer> mapBinder = 
    MapBinder.newMapBinder(binder(), MyInterface.class, Integer.class);
mapBinder.addBinding(MyInterfaceImpl1.class).to(5);
mapBinder.addBinding(MyInterfaceImpl2.class).to(6);
```

This is illegal though, since addBinding expects a instance of the class.

I know I could switch the order of the objects in the map, but the integer values are not unique so then I'd end up with a Map of Integer -> List, which is rather ugly.  Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MapBinder is not going to work for you.  The mapping is from static keys to provided values, not the other way around.

Perhaps a more concrete description of what you're trying to do would help uncover a solution.

Also, take a look at [Multiset](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release02/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multiset.html) for mapping a type to an integer.  I'm not sure if you're modeling a count or not, but it seems like it might fit for what you're trying to do.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Thats what I assumed, but figured it was worth checking to see if someone had another idea. I think I came up with a different solution that will work for me.